# Defer some daemon startups until after disk idle at boot

Tags: debian, systemd, daemon

**Background:** I have a laptop running Debian testing/unstable and booting with systemd. It's got a normal laptop magnetic hard drive (not an SSD). The machine is set to auto-login when turned on, so it goes straight from system bootup, to desktop loading—which is KDE 5, not exactly lightweight.

There are a few daemons I'd like to set to only start after the desktop is fully loaded (e.g., PostgreSQL, exim, apache, …) to get a usable desktop quicker. "Desktop fully loaded" can be detected fairly easily: the disk goes idle.

**Question:** Is there some systemd feature for launching system daemons only once the desktop is fully up? I've looked through the docs, and there doesn't seem to be anything after `graphical.target`. I feel I must be missing something, with all the features systemd has.

A few things I've thought of:

- PostgreSQL at least does not support socket activation, so that's not an
  option.
- There are `Type=idle` services, but it sounds like that'd maybe wait until `sddm` is started, but not until the desktop is loaded.
- Write a service that is wanted by `graphical.target` that checks every 10s for the amount of disk activity, and if there is none, uses systemctl to start a `local-idle.target` or similar (then exists). Trying to avoid this one.

Comment: maybe `inotify`, there'd have to be some file/directory that is written/accessed when destkop is fully loaded

Comment: @gwillie I presume you mean with [path activation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html)? That might work, but seems very fragile. E.g., KDE upgrade changes file access order or stops using the targeted file. Interesting idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is *no such event* as "the desktop is fully up". There is no way to detect such a condition in a generic way.

How would you formally define it? The DE's own autostart mechanisms (`/etc/xdg/autostart`, `~/.config/autostart` etc.) are not controlled by systemd; it has no way of knowing whether the DE had finished its start-up.

Moreover, the disk may never get idle. What if you started up the system in haste and immediately started doing something?

So, you have to decide what do *you* understand by "the desktop going fully up" and then simply write a script which detects this condition and starts another target with all your heavy services. So it's really the third option.